# Adding a sub path for App_Themes in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, themes, subdirectory, app-themes

I am going to be using my App_Themes folder for three separate sites running from the same environment, so will have a folder structure like:

- App_Themes/SiteUK/Default
- App_Themes/SiteUS/Default
- App_Themes/SiteAU/Default

Each site directory will contain various themes (Clothes, Shoes etc). How can configure / define a leading directory (i.e SiteUK). IIS wont work for this. Here's my code at the moment, before moving it into the sub directories, which is working:

```
private void SetPageTheme(string categoryName)
{  
    switch (categoryName)
    {
        case "Clothes":
        case "Shoes":
            Page.Theme = categoryName;
            break;
        default:
            Page.Theme = "Default";
            break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be amazing web geniuses.